# Add design attributes dynamically with add button

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata, ui, design-attributes

In many standard LWC components, I have seen design attributes can be added dynamically with a **+ Add** button. See the screenshot below.

Can we achieve the same thing for custom components?

[image]